# What are best practices to synchronize multiple git branches?

Tags: git

For example, Gitlab indicates that the develop branch is behind master:

Example 1

[image]

Example 2

[image]

One could make a merge request from master to develop, but as there are no code changes it seems impossible to align these branches.

The current approach is to remove the develop branch once in a while and to create it again in order to get `0 | 0` again.

The `1|0` means that this branch is 1 behind the master branch, `5|0` means 5 commits behind the master branch and `2|3` means two behind master branch and 3 ahead.

**Branching strategy**

1. The develop is branched from the master, i.e. `0|0`
2. A feature branch is created from the develop
3. When the feature is ready the code from the feature branch will be merged into the develop
4. A release branch is created from the develop branch
5. The release branch will be merged into master

Comment: Could you explain what `0 | 0` or `5 | 0` means? Also: what kind of branching strategy are you using: When do you merge into master? Are you using merge commits, or fast-forward merges that don't create a new commit?

Comment: can you explain your branching strategy more? development branches should never be behind master unless you have multiple paths to master that don't go through development. re-branching dev to get in sync isn't a bad thing, but its usually because dev gets too many orphaned changes that don't and shouldn't ever get merged.

Comment: @Ryathal the branching strategy has been added to the question

Comment: Have a look at Gitflow: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: When you want both branches to keep the same state then why do you have mutliple branches? If you want to get changes from A to B and vice versa just merge back and forth.